# Toggling Between State Value - Toggle Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

In my React App, I have a functional component and wanted to toggle between a state's value. My `toggleNav` function doesn't seem to working. I'm trying to set `isMenuOpen` to what `isMenuOpen` is not but my syntax seems to be incorrect.

I have the following code:

```
const navBar = () => {

  //set initial state
  const [isMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  // toggle variable
  let toggleNav = () => {
    isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={toggleNav}>Toggle</button>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second element returned by `useState` is a `setter`. You can't just mutate the state. Try this:

```
const navBar = () => {

  //set initial state
  const [isMenuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  // toggle variable
  let toggleNav = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={toggleNav}>Toggle</button>
  )

}
```

As pointed out in comments, `toggleNav` is unecessary:

```
const navBar = () => {

  //set initial state
  const [isMenuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);


  return (
    <button onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)}>Toggle</button>
  )

}
```

Comment: why even define `toggleNav` at all, and better yet why define it with `let`? this is incredibly wasteful programming. just `{e=>setMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)}` would be sufficient

Comment: just modify his example. I wouldn't declare `toggleNav` either

Comment: @r3wt is it considered wasteful because I only use it once? Therefor should use inline?

Comment: I don't believe to be a performance issue. Just a lot of unecessary code

Comment: The time expended declaring a variable is negligible in such a small component

Comment: got it, thanks @Dupocas Biggest takeaway for me here is the setter element. ty!